# Prettier format is not working in vscode, it shows some error

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
["INFO" - 11:47:04 AM] Formatting completed in 44ms.
["INFO" - 12:16:47 PM] Formatting file:///d%3A/Javascript/Work/01-Fundamentals-Part-1/index.html
["ERROR" - 12:16:47 PM] Invalid prettier configuration file detected.
["ERROR" - 12:16:47 PM] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\node_modules\prettier'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\node_modules\prettier'
["ERROR" - 12:16:47 PM] Invalid prettier configuration file detected. See log for details.
```

My code is not formatting even though in my setting formatOnSave is enabled and default formatter is prettier

Comment: *Invalid prettier configuration file detected.*

Comment: *Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\node_modules\prettier'*